# JSX can be used without importing React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to run my first React JSX file with create-react-app with version 4.0.0 and it works! However, I don't have the import statements of React included in my JSX and it works too but it is very weird. The project is created by **create-react-app** command with version 4.0.0.

The App.js file:

/* without import React but works too! */

```js
 import { Component } from "react";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>456</div>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Comment: You must be enjoying the new JSX transform: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html . Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the new features of CRA 4/React 17. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-2020-10-23

Answer (score 25):

Starting from **React 17** it's not necessary to import **React** to use **JSX**. See from the blog post about that in the section called [Removing Unused React Imports](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#removing-unused-react-imports):

> Because the new JSX transform will automatically import the necessary react/jsx-runtime functions, React will no longer need to be in scope when you use JSX. This might lead to unused React imports in your code.

**What’s a JSX Transform?**

> Browsers don’t understand JSX out of the box, so most React users rely on a compiler like Babel or TypeScript to transform JSX code into regular JavaScript.

Suggested read is [Introducing the New JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html). Also you can see [Using React 17 and the new JSX transform with Create React App 4.0 Alpha](https://gist.github.com/iansu/4fab7a9bfa5fa6ebc87a908c62f5340b).

Answer (score 11):

This is new with the [JSX transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) introduced with `React 17` :

> Together with the React 17 release, we’ve wanted to make a few
> improvements to the JSX transform, but we didn’t want to break
> existing setups. This is why we worked with Babel to **offer a new,
> rewritten version of the JSX transform** for people who would like to
> upgrade.
>
> Upgrading to the new transform is completely optional, but it has a
> few benefits:
>
> - With the new transform, you can **use JSX without importing React**.
> - Depending on your setup, its compiled output may **slightly improve the bundle size**.
> - It will enable future improvements that **reduce the number of concepts** you need to learn React.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}
```

Earlier react jsx used to transform element using React.createElement(). There was no automatic insertion:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello world');
}
```

Now, jsx is [transpiled by a compiler automatically](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html).

```
// Inserted by a compiler
import {jsx as _jsx} from 'react/jsx-runtime';

function App() {
  return _jsx('h1', { children: 'Hello world' });
}
```

Thus, we don't need to import `React` component unless we need to use `React` explicitly. For eg.

```
import React from 'react' // without it, compiler will fail
class Foo extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return <h1>hello</h1>
 }
}
```