# Why is this React tutorial App.js missing import as shown in the Mozilla tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started

Which clearly says that the component won't work without the first import listed

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
```

I just created my first tutorial app, opened `App.js` and it is not there.  Yet I can `npm start` run it without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three import statements.

`import React from 'react';`
Stackoverflow already has a bunch of questions with answers about it (as an example: [JSX can be used without importing React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541040/jsx-can-be-used-without-importing-react)). Short answer: this import can be missed since React 17.

`import logo from './logo.svg';`
Here is an assignment of some value to the `logo` variable (by Webpack); therefore, the `logo` will be `undefined` if this import is missed. Apparently, your application can successfully start with an undefined `logo`.

`import './App.css';`
This import adds some styles to a component (by Webpack). So, your application has default browser styles without it.

That's why your application can be started without these import statements.

Comment: Mozilla is not up to date?  That is surprising.